# how to migrate mysql db to sql anywhere

Tags: mysql, sqlanywhere

I have a db in **mysql**, and I want to migrate it to **sql anywhere**.  Anyone knows how to do it?

I don't want to export the `csv` file from `mysql`, then import the `csv` file into `sql anywhere`.  Is there another solution which could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the documentation of migration from [here](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/Migrating+a+MySQL+Database+to+SQL+Anywhere+16).

Basically, you could use the sybase's built-in function to do this.

1. Create a db on SQL Anywhere which you want to move your MySQL db to.
2. Create a remote server to access the MySQL db from SQL Anywhere.
3. Follow the instructions in the [migration documentation](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/Migrating+a+MySQL+Database+to+SQL+Anywhere+16) to move the db.

Note: I only did this on Windows OS, since I only set up odbc driver successfully on Windows.